# Foundation topbar is_hover false only for touch devices

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am wanting a topbar that is hover for non-touch devices and click for touch devices.

I have achieved this by doing it this way:

```
 <nav class="top-bar show-for-touch" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: false">
        <!-- menu -->
 </nav>
 <nav class="top-bar hide-for-touch" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: true">
        <!-- menu -->
 </nav>
```

However there must be a cleaner way of doing it without repeating the entire menu twice, I have searched the documentation and online and have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
:hover
```

will work as hover on non touch devices and still work as click or tap on touch devices...If iam not mistaken